# Feeding individual examples into TensorFlow graph trained on files?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm new to TensorFlow and am getting a bit tripped up on the mechanics of reading data. I set up a TensorFlow graph on the mnist data, but I'd like to modify it so that I can run one program to train it + save the model out, and run another to load said graph, make predictions, and compute test accuracy.

Where I'm getting confused is how to bypass the original I/O system in the training graph and "inject" an image to predict or an (image, label) tuple of test data for accuracy testing. To read the training data, I'm using this code:

```
_, input_data = util.read_examples(
    paths_to_files,
    batch_size,
    shuffle=shuffle,
    num_epochs=None)

feature_map = {
    'label': tf.FixedLenFeature(
    shape=[], dtype=tf.int64, default_value=[-1]),
    'image': tf.FixedLenFeature(
    shape=[NUM_PIXELS * NUM_PIXELS], dtype=tf.int64),
}
example = tf.parse_example(input_data, features=feature_map)
```

I then feed example to a convolution layer, etc. and generate the output.

Now imagine that I train my graph with that code specifying the input, save out the graph and weights, and then restore the graph and weights in another script for prediction -- I'd like to take (say) 10 images and feed them to the graph to generate predictions. How do I "inject" those 10 images so that the predictions come out the other end?

I played around with feed dictionaries and placeholders, but I'm not sure if they're the right things for me to use... it seems like they rely on having data in memory, as opposed to reading from a queue of test data, for example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A feed dictionary with placeholders would make sense if you wanted to perform a small number of inferences/evaluations (i.e. enough to fit in memory) - e.g. if you were serving a simple model or running small eval loops.

If you specifically want to infer or evaluate large batches then you should use the same approach you've used for training, but with a different path to your test/eval/live data. e.g.

```
_, eval_data = util.read_examples(
    paths_to_files,  # CHANGE THIS BIT
    batch_size,
    shuffle=shuffle,
    num_epochs=None)
```

You can use this as a normal python variable and set up successive, dependent steps to use this as a provided variable. e.g.

```
def get_example(data):
    return tf.parse_example(data, features=feature_map)

sess.run([get_example(path_to_your_data)])
```

Comment: ok cool, that makes sense. what I'm having trouble wrapping my head around is how this works when loading my graph -- the original util.read_examples node is in that graph somewhere and I have to bypass or modify it somehow. is the easiest thing just to rearrange my graph to remove it and add a new feeding node?

Comment: Ahh - it is common to build slightly different graphs for inference & training but I think the simplest solution is to use the same graph but provide a feed dict at inference time. You can pass the tensor you want replaced as the key in the dict and the value you want for that tensor as the value. I think in your example you could use `sess.run([your_inference_tensors], { example['image']: your_image_data })`. Check the [Session.run()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run) docs for more clarity.